# Push notification sounds (iOS)

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I submitted an app to the app store for push notifications with no sound:

`let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .alert], categories: nil)`

In the next build, I will include sound for notifications:

`let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .alert, .sound], categories: nil)`

When a user installs the update, I am concerned that they will not have sound for their notification b/c they have already accepted push notifications without sound.  How do I go about ensuring push notifcations have sound on update?  I don't think I can ask to enable push notifications after it's already been enabled..

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Simple show an alert when the app starts for the first time after the update, informing the user that you added sound and that they should change their push settings accordingly. You can add a direct link to the Settings app by opening the URL `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` to the alert.